# does fsync on the root directory of an ext4 volume flush all children?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

does fsync() on a directory guarantee that directory and all children are flushed as well?

so assume I have

```
   foo
   |- bar
   |- baz
   |  |--file
```

if I write 'file' and then fsync on foo will the contents of 'file' be guranteed to be flushed (as well as the meta data for foo and baz)

Answer (score 4):

fsync() on a directory will flush the file names in that specific directory.(E.g.: if new files are created, the names/nodes will be flushed). Won't impact the content of files, you will need to call fsync() on the specific file for that. It's not recursive.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, `fsync()` on a directory isn't guaranteed to do anything at all. The Linux man page defines it as flushing buffer cache pages for the file referenced; since directories don't *have* buffer cache pages, it may very well just return immediately.

It would almost certainly not flush buffer cache pages for files contained within the directory unless it simply flushed the whole volume -- determining which files are stored recursively within the referenced directory could potentially be a very expensive operation (like, on the scale of minutes to hours) if `foo` pointed to a large directory tree. So it won't do that.

If you want to flush files without referencing them specifically, use `sync()`. It'll be overly broad (by flushing the buffer cache for every single file on every single volume), but it will get the job done. The manual explains:

> According to the standard specification  (e.g.,  POSIX.1-2001),  sync()
>   schedules the writes, but may return before the actual writing is done.
>   However, since version 1.3.20 Linux does actually  wait.   (This  still
>   does not guarantee data integrity: modern disks have large caches.)

Comment: overly broad is fine for me, in fact thats what I want - however I understand sync() doesn't guarantee the contents were written due to disk caches, etc.  I also understand some disks lie and say they have flushed when asked, but assuming the disk does what it's supposed to do (flush) then is sync() the correct call?  will it both block until the Linux cache has flushed and the disk cache has flushed as well?

Comment: See doc extract I added. Synopsis: It will block until the Linux cache has flushed, but not the disk cache because that isn't exposed. Disk write cache tends to be pretty small outside of RAID cards, though. (And those are battery-backed so they're fine.)

Comment: this seems strange - if this is the case, how can a transaction be completed?  I'm not confident there arent calls for flushing disk caches,  my understanding is that some controllers lie, but the API does exist.

assuming one does exist, does linux have it implemented